# Not able to connect mysql with django

Tags: mysql, django

I am not able to connect mysql with django. Each time i unistall mysql i face this problem and i stuck there for 2,3 hours becuse of two things one solved and i want this one to be solved. I have to google a lot then only i found the answer. Please someone tell me how to solve this because this is so irritating sometime.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'manasdb',
    'USER':'root',
    'PASSWORD':''
}
```

}

How to solve this folllowing error

```
 super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")
```

Comment: could you please post more detailed code? What is the code inside the Connection class?

Comment: is your db username and password are correct. this occurs sometimes when there is no password for you mysql add password to your mysql it will work

Comment: Did you try to pass in the default dictionary 'HOST' : 'yourmysqlhostname' ?
Consider to creating a password to your mysql also for security reasons.

Comment: Yeah Everything is correct. I solved it. Thank you brothers. Actually some version problem is there with Django 2.2 so its not working sometime. After googling it solved.

Answer (score 0):

After Googling i found this answer

```
$ sudo mysql -u root # I had to use "sudo" since is new installation
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

$ service mysql restart
```